# parameter in cloud functions is undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have an old code for Google Cloud Functions, it resized an image to create a thumbnail, I wrote it three years ago and was in NodeJS 6, it was working fine but i had to update to NodeJS 10, i added

```
"engines": {
    "node": "10"
  }
```

other functions continued working but this not

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const contentType = object.contentType;
```

it throws an error when i try to access "object" apparently is undefined, the log error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined
    at exports.generateThumbnail.functions.storage.object.onFinalize (/workspace/index.js:30:32)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:120:23)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I updated firebase-admin, firebase-functions, google-cloud-storage, but it did not solve my problem
What could have happened and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you share you `package.json` file?

Comment: There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/456#issuecomment-498415497) with the same error you are getting the solution proposed was to set a new environment variable at the beggining of the `index.js` like the following: `process.env.X_GOOGLE_NEW_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE = true;` can you try that?

Comment: @RafaelLemos Thank you, it solved my problem like a charm

Comment: @LABR Great, I will make this into an answer, please consider accepting it so that others in the community that go through the same issue can find this solution more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/456#issuecomment-498415497) other users were facing the same issue you are, the propose solution had to do with the need to set a new variable in order to refresh the objects in your function and redeploying it.

So, if you were to add a new variable to your to your `index.js` like this:

```
process.env.X_GOOGLE_NEW_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE = true;
```

And redeploy the function, the issue is suppose to be fixed.